# Use substring_index to search after first comma and second comma

Tags: mysql, inner-join

This is the SQL query i can use for the first

```
update Table1 t1
        inner join Table2 t2
        on  SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.Location, ',', 1) = t2.Location 
    SET t1.Latitude = t2.Latitude ,
        t1.Longitude = t2.Longitude
```

As an example the above query will show Manchester as it comes first in within the column: Manchester, Derby, Birmingham

But I also want to step a query that can search Derby or Birmingham so if need be can go beyond the first comma.

Comment: Just to clarify i would like to be able to query the above say after the first comma or second comma.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
update Table1 t1
        inner join Table2 t2
        on  find_in_set(t2.location, t1.Location) > 0
    SET t1.Latitude = t2.Latitude ,
        t1.Longitude = t2.Longitude
```

This also lets you search for a particular location, such as the 2nd:

```
update Table1 t1
        inner join Table2 t2
        on  find_in_set(t2.location, t1.Location) = 2
    SET t1.Latitude = t2.Latitude ,
        t1.Longitude = t2.Longitude
```

Comment: This is very slow performance wise on large data sets. Is there a way by using full text index?

Comment: @user1967987 . . . If performance is an issue, then you should look into properly normalizing the location list in t1.  This is probably a better approach than applying full text search to a list of tags.